# Error when using custom domain with Next.js on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have deployed a site using Next.js on Heroku. With the domain Heroku provides everything works fine:

https://weboost.herokuapp.com/

When I add a custom domain, the site loads but then throws an error:

https://search.weboost.com/

**Error:**

`Minified React error #32; visit http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=32&args[]=3 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
Invariant Violation: Minified React error #32;`

I'm really stumped as to why it is fine with one domain, and errors out with another. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT

Here is the function that returns the Head component:

```
import Head from 'next/head';

export default () => (
  <Head>
     <title>Weboost</title>
     <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
     <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
  </Head>
);
```

Comment: The full text of the error you just encountered is: "Unable to find element with ID 3." Are you looking for an element with ID 3 that does not exist? Is this something you are getting from a database?

Comment: can you show the render func that renders `header` ? I mean `Parent of Header`

Comment: @Pather I put the Head component in the edit.

Comment: @GovindRai nothing on that page is returning any data so I'm not sure what the ID error would be from.

Comment: I mean, the Header component, that renders Header, nav tags. Can you show the parent who renders those ?

Comment: I think i found your error. Can you turn-off(for now turn of all HTML, CSS, JS) AutoMinify in cloudfare. https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/201539228/AutoMinify.png and purge the cache on cloudfare. Then open search.weboost.com in incognito window ?

Comment: @Panther sorry about that. I'll do what you said on Cloudflare.

Comment: @Panther it works! Do you know what was causing it to do that?